# How to post a form?

Tags: post, http-post

I got an URL. There is a form in that URL and I know it's name and the form action.

E.g:

url:

```
www.abc.com/123.html
```

form:

```
<form action="POST.php" method="post" name="form">
    <input id="id" name="name" type="text">
</form>
```

My question is how do I post this form and get the response? It seems some functions in PHP like fget and fputs have a security violation and i don't want to use them. I have tried several answers but they didn't work well. Any programming language is fine.

Answer (score 1):

POST is, to the contrary GET, the more secure way to get data to the Server. If you want the "answer" from the server displayed in the same page you go with AJAX.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Here is a possible jQuery solution:

HTML:

```
<form action="POST.php" method="post" name="form">
    <input id="id" name="name" type="text">
    <button id="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<div id="serverresponse"></div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo("Name is: " . $_POST['name']);
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "POST.php",
        data: $('#id').serialize(),
        async: false,
        success: function(response){
            $("#serverresponse").html(response);
        },
        error: function(text){
            $("#serverresponse").html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This sends the content of the "name" input to the POST.php witch is just returning it and the response is displayed in the "serverresponse" div.

But you have to make sure jQuery is loaded.

Comment: I wanted to post to a remote form. I have an url provided.